# Dynamic Memory Allocation and Memory Leaks

Tags: c, matlab, memory-management, mex

I am writing a matlab mex function using c code. I am having a little trouble freeing allocated memory. I am having trouble with the following code. If I get rid of all the free() lines, the code works but I have memory leaks. This means that the code works only a few times before I run out of memory. All the functions called have pointers as inputs so I am never changing the address of the pointer within the functions. Am I making a mistake in the memory allocation/freeing procedure?

```
void RLS_(int *M, int *N, double *h, double *y, double *P, double *theta)
{

int i;
double *Ph;//[*M];
double hPh;
double inv;
double *inv1;
double *invPh;//[*M];
double *hTtheta;//[*N];
double *ymhTtheta;//[*N];
double **ADD;//[*M][*N];
double **invPhhT;//[*M][*M];
double **SUB;//[*M][*M];

Ph = (double *) malloc (*M * sizeof(double));
if (Ph == NULL)
    return;

invPh = (double *) malloc (*M * sizeof(double));
if ( invPh == NULL)
    return;

hTtheta = (double *) malloc (*N * sizeof(double));
if (hTtheta == NULL)
    return;

ymhTtheta = (double *) malloc (*N * sizeof(double));
if (ymhTtheta == NULL)
    return;

ADD = (double **) malloc (*M * sizeof(double *));
if (ADD == NULL)
    return;
for (i=0;i<*M;i++)
{
    ADD[i] = (double *) malloc(*N *sizeof(double));
    if (ADD[i] == NULL)
        return;
}
invPhhT = (double **) malloc (*M * sizeof(double *));
if (invPhhT == NULL)
    return;
for (i=0;i<*M;i++)
{
    invPhhT[i] = (double *) malloc(*M *sizeof(double));
    if (invPhhT[i] == NULL)
        return;
}
SUB = (double **) malloc (*M * sizeof(double *));
if (SUB == NULL)
    return;
for (i=0;i<*M;i++)
{
    SUB[i] = (double *) malloc(*M *sizeof(double));   
    if (SUB[i] == NULL)
        return;
}


matvectmult_(M,M,P,h,Ph);                  

hPh = vectordot_(M,h,Ph);                   

inv = 1/(1+hPh); inv1 =&inv;

scalarmult_(M,inv1,Ph,invPh);               

vectmatmult_(M,N,theta,h,hTtheta);          

vectorsub_(N,y,hTtheta,ymhTtheta);          

vectvectmult_(M,N,invPh,ymhTtheta,*ADD);    

vectvectmult_(M,M,invPh,h,*invPhhT);     

matmulc_(M,M,M,*invPhhT,P,*SUB);           

// Update theta
matrixadd_(M,N,theta,*ADD,theta);

// Update P
matrixsub_(M,M,P,*SUB,P);               

free(Ph);
free(invPh);
free(hTtheta);
free(ymhTtheta);
for (i=0;i<*M;i++)
    free(ADD[i]);
free(ADD);
for (i=0;i<*M;i++)
    free(invPhhT[i]);
free(invPhhT);
for (i=0;i<*M;i++)
    free(SUB[i]);
free(SUB);
}
```

Comment: I dont see anything MATLAB or MEX related, this is pure C.. Perhaps you can use MEX API functions to allocate memory like [`mxMalloc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcalloc.html) (which is automatically freed by MATLAB memory manager upon MEX-function exit).

Comment: Why are you not using `mxMalloc` and `mxFree`? Are you using "mex.h"?

Comment: Because I didnt know those existed. Is there any benefit to using mxMalloc instead of malloc?

Comment: Straight from [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxmalloc.html): "`mxMalloc` allocates contiguous heap space sufficient to hold `n` bytes. Use `mxMalloc` instead of the ANSI® C `malloc` function to allocate memory in MATLAB applications." Any memory that is passed from mex code back into Matlab should be allocated this way. Straight C versions can work, but there'll be issues and you might not discover them until later.

Comment: Because you are allocating and freeing the memory locally, you do not *need* to use mxMalloc--you're not passing any of these objects back to MATLAB.

Comment: You call a lot of functions that are taking pointers. Most of these functions don't return anything, so I assume they accomplish something useful by modifying the object(s) some if their parameters point to or reassigning the pointer. It would be helpful to know what changes all those functions are making. It would be a big help if anything that doesn't need to be a pointer (M and N perhaps?) wasn't, and anything that needs to be a pointer for performance reasons only was "as const as you can make it" if your compiler supports it.

Comment: I don't see any obvious leak here. (Unless it's inside those other functions that are being called. Do they themselves call `malloc`, and do they free their local memory, or memory they're replacing?)  Depending on the size of `M` and what else you're doing, you may be getting memory fragmentation instead of a true leak. Check what `feature memstats` says after you run out of memory: if you have lots of total memory available, but small blocks, you may be seeing fragmentation.

Comment: Also, like @horchler says, `mxMalloc` may be a good idea. You don't *need* to use `mxMalloc` for local allocations, but maybe you *should*. It's free garbage collection! Your leak, if any, should go away if you use `mxMalloc` everywhere because Matlab will automatically `mxFree` any memory that you forget to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one point - you have many, many return statements and you don't ever free any memory before any of these calls. For example, if if invPh is NULL, then the memory allocated for Ph will not be released.

Comment: Good point in general, but all those early `returns` in this particular code only get hit in the case of `malloc` failure, in which case he's already run out of memory, so they're unlikely to be the root cause of the leak.

Answer (score 0):

Considering what @Owen said, I would put your `malloc` statements in a do-while loop that only executes once, and replace all of your `return` statements with `break` instead.

```
do {
    // mxMalloc
    if (someVar[i] == NULL)
        break;

    // etc...
    // The real meat of your code inside the do-while loop
} while 0 == 1;
// mxFree functions out here
```

I am a little rusty on coding mex functions. There is probably a better practice for doing this, but that might help.

You also probably need to check that each of the variables you are trying to free is `!= NULL` as well, although the `free` function might do this automatically.

**EDIT**: Changed the above code. I think @horchler in the comments said it best: you should use `mxMalloc` and `mxFree` instead of `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: There is a problem here. `free(NULL)` is by definition a no-op, so there's no reason to check for it. However, if you use this do/while/break logic, in the case of an early `break`, any of the variables that didn't get allocated yet will have uninitialized contents, so you could end up calling `free()` on a random pointer, which is undefined behavior (i.e. a possibly memory-corrupting bug). This is probably not a good approach unless extra guards or initialization are added. Factoring out deallocation to a separate function might be an alternative.